# how to switch back to svc mode from hyp mode using ELR_Hyp in armv7

Tags: assembly, arm, hypervisor

I have been able to put my processor to hyp mode from svc mode using the command `hvc #0`. I did some register read and write operations on HVBAR and I want to get back to supervisor mode.
I tried the following ways:

1. copied the sp and lr before calling the hvc and then restored them after the register operations are over. Then branched to the link register value.

   ```
   mov r5,sp;  
   mov r6,lr;  
   bx lr;
   ```
2. I also tried the old method of passing the link register directly to the program counter

   ```
   mov pc,lr;
   ```
3. I tried to do an svc call from the hyp mode and expected it to change the processor state to supervisor mode

   ```
   svc #0;
   ```
4. I have used the `eret` instruction in the end of register operations to see whether it will have an effect. It didn't have any impact .

But none of this caused the processor to change the state. After running the code  The mode  in my CPSR and SPSR is the non secure hypervisor mode only .
After a literature survey I got an idea that I have to work with the ELR_Hyp register since I am using the virtualization extensions. But I am failing to understand how to use the ELR_Hyp for returning to Supervisor mode from Hyp mode .

Comment: Fairly sure you need an exception return (not just a branch), I think this is an explicit instruction in ARMv7 (but I don't have time to check right now)

Comment: @achoora Could you please share your code for entering hyp mode? I mean all the preparation before being able to call "hvc #0". There is no code for it on the whole web.

Comment: @Joey Sorry Dude , I understand the concern but the code I have written is proprietary now. arm architecture reference manual has every thing you need. especially page B1136. You have to take care of the stacks while returning from the modes if you want to preserve the context.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping down from Hyp mode to a PL1 mode is much like dropping from a PL1 mode to User mode; it's an exception return. The only difference is you have to use the specific [`eret` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1361289871515.html), rather than `movs pc, lr` and friends.

Comment: Well then there's clearly more than the basics at play. What's the mode in SPSR_hyp? It could be that you're taking nested exceptions (e.g. your `svc` will still be taken in Hyp mode, and at that point you're stuck because you've now overwritten the previous ELR/SPSR). Furthermore, the fact that someone was around to answer your `hvc` call in the first place implies that you already have a hypervisor running, and that's probably not too happy about having its system register state messed with.

Comment: The mode in SPSR_hyp is also  NSHyp i.e Hypervisor mode

Comment: OK, it's not much of a surprise that returning from Hyp mode to Hyp mode stays in Hyp mode.

Comment: Yes so how would I return to supervisor mode in this case ?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, move the CPSR and PC values you want into the SPSR and ELR respectively, then `eret` to them. If you really came up from SVC and have subsequently lost the original values (as opposed to initially booting or context-switching a VM, when Hyp is initialising SVC with whatever it wants to), then you've got other problems.

Comment: Yes I started in SVC only. I will recheck all the registers and the values. Whether some flag in any Hyp related register is causing this behavior